# Setting Variable in Class that Extends other class

Tags: java, arrays, super

the psuedo for what im trying to do is

```
-send Array of EMPLOYEE objects to Restaurant Class
-In Class RESTAURANT give each of the employee objects a name and last name (last name not in employee Class but in PERSON Class which Employee CLass Extends.
-print say employeeList[1].getLastName()
```

hopefully my code explains better

```
class Person {
    public Person(final String last) {

    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    private String firstName;

    // getFirstName method
    // getLastName Method

    Employee(final String first, final String last) {
        super(last);
    }
}

class Restaurant { // set first object in array have first and last name

    public void setFirstLast(final Employee[] employeeList) {
        String firstName = "Jovana";
        String lastName = "Valdez";
        employeeList[0] = new Employee(firstName, lastName); // set up via constructor
    }
}

public class Main {

    private String lastName;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Employee[] employeeList = new Employee[1]; // my array of Employee objects, all set to null

        Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
        restaurant.setFirstLast(employeeList); 

    }

}
```

from main when i try to print `System.out.printf("first is %d\n",arrayList.getFirst());` i get null for the value as well as the value for the last name so what is the correct way to go about and set values to objects in the array?

Edit arrayList initialized in Class restaurant by

```
public Table[] create_table_array(Table table,int number) {
    Table[] TableList = new Table[number];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        TableList[i] = table;
    }
    return TableList;
```

Comment: Are you sure, is it java? `Class` should be `class` and `setFirstLast` not returning anything, we need to know how `employeeList` is initialized

Comment: yea when i run it under netbeans ide i get null for bothe first and last names

Comment: Okay, assuming that you trimmed it to make question readable, but your code can not compile. As maszter told, you are missing assigning `fistName` along with the above listed ones

Comment: okay and how would the last name be initizlized since its part of a different class?

Comment: In your `Person` class, make your constructor like `public Person(String last) { lastName = last; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor doesn't save firstName, it should look like:

```
Employee(String first, String last) {
    super(last);
    firstName = first;
}
```

Comment: thanks, how do you set the last name though, since its part of another class?

Comment: Person(String last) { lastName = last; }

Answer (score 0):

You did not make good constructor of Person class and it class does not have instance variable lastName in which you should assign value you get in constructor as a parameter.

Also constructor of Employee does not assign any value to firstName.

What ArrayList ?As i see you are working with arrays?I didn't see it in code anywhere?
`System.out.printf("first is %d\n",**arrayList**.getFirst());`so command is wrong.

Any code that has meaning to me and can be compilled is to fix those things and delete formatting options you putted in `System.out.printf` because you are not formatting numbers.

So code look like :

```
    class Person {
    String lastName;

    public Person(final String last) {
        lastName=last;
    }
}

    class Employee extends Person {
        private String firstName;

        public String getFirstName()
        {return firstName;}

        public String getLastName()
        {return lastName;}

        Employee(final String first, final String last) {
            super(last);
            firstName=first;
        }
    }
    class Restaurant { // set first object in array have first and last name

    public void setFirstLast(final Employee[] employeeList) {
        String firstName = "Jovana";
        String lastName = "Valdez";
        employeeList[0] = new Employee(firstName, lastName); // set up via constructor
    }
}

    public class Main {

    private String lastName;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Employee[] employeeList = new Employee[1]; 

        Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
        restaurant.setFirstLast(employeeList); 
        System.out.printf("first is "+employeeList[0].getFirstName()+"  "+employeeList[0].getLastName());

    }

}
```